# Is it possible to filter chart without refresh?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, office-365, chart

I have created a chart in excel using PowerPivot and I am using oData Data Feed to get values from my SharePoint List. I have set auto refresh at every 60 minutes and I have used some filters also.

I have displayed my chart using Excel Web Access web part and following properties are set to the web part.

1. All PivotTable & PivotChart Interactivity

Now what happens is my chart is not updated at particular period and if I am trying to filter for the first time after page load it is asking for confirmation to refresh the workbook as below.

[image: Excel Query and Refresh confirmation box]

Is is possible to avoid this confirmation? If yes then how?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I have the same question.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find any proper solution for this. I have searched through many links and found that it is not refreshing it self even if we have set period to refresh automatically. 
Right now I have to open that file in browser using Office Web App and then refresh the connection and then Save the file again.